# Fourier transform for $\exp(ix^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the Fourier transform of generalized functions

${\rm exp}(ix^2)$

My solution: I take the integral for all $\mathbb{R}$

$F({\rm exp}(ix^2))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int {\rm exp}(iy^2-ixy)dy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int {\rm exp}[(\sqrt{i}y-\frac{ix}{2\sqrt{i}})^2-\frac{ix^2}{4}]dy=$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\rm exp}(\frac{-ix^2}{4})\int {\rm exp}(\sqrt{i}y-\frac{\sqrt{i}x}{2})^2dy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\rm exp}(\frac{-ix^2}{4})\int {\rm exp}(-i(\sqrt{i}y-\frac{\sqrt{i}x}{2})i)^2dy$

Then I make a replacement

$u=-i(\sqrt{i}y-\frac{\sqrt{i}x}{2}), du=-i\sqrt{i}dy$

But I do not know in which area to integrate now.
Maybe I counted incorrectly

Comment: Use `${\rm exp}(x)$` for ${\rm exp}(x)$. What you have now means $e\times x\times p$, *etc.*

Comment: Duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188392/fourier-transform-of-e-ix2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fourier transform of $e^{-i|x|^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188392/fourier-transform-of-e-ix2)

Comment: Using `\operatorname{exp}` will produce better results in certain contexts than `{\rm exp}`, e.g., when not using parentheses around the argument.